# MFC SetTitle() causing weird debug assertion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, mfc

Whenever I call SetTitle() in my MFC application, I get a debug assertion failed. But I haven't set to assert anything; in truth I'm not really sure how to explain what's going on.

I actually get three debug assertions that loop round continuously about a dozen times before the application continues. If I keep clicking "Ignore" then after about 20 clicks the boxes go away and the applciation continues running as normal.

The first two assertions are thrown from wincore.cpp lines 952 and 954. The area of code is:

```
else if (m_hWnd == HWND_NOTOPMOST)
    ASSERT(this == &CWnd::wndNoTopMost);
else
{
    // should be a normal window
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

    // should also be in the permanent or temporary handle map
    CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND();
    ASSERT(pMap != NULL);

    CObject* p=NULL;
    if(pMap)
    {
        ASSERT( (p = pMap->LookupPermanent(m_hWnd)) != NULL ||
                (p = pMap->LookupTemporary(m_hWnd)) != NULL);
    }
    ASSERT((CWnd*)p == this);   // must be us
```

The third assertion is thrown from dbgrptt.c, line 85. The offending code snippet is:

```
_CRTIMP void _cdecl _CrtDbgBreak(
    void
    )
{
    __debugbreak();
}
```

(it's breaking at the __debugbreak() function).

I am not really sure where to start with this. My call stack is visible here: http://s18.postimg.org/lhoz1rwqh/callstack.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It *looks* like you're calling `CDocument::SetTitle()` while the associated view is either not created yet or already destroyed. Can you investigate along these lines?

Comment: Interesting.. because the view is there and SetTitle DOES work... (If I ignore all the assertions, or run a release version).

Comment: Apparently `::IsWindow(m_hWnd)` returns `FALSE`. Can you double-check that the view's `Create()` method has been called and that its `m_hWnd` member is not `NULL`?

Comment: Oh sorry I think I wasn't clear: in the first code snippets, the asserting lines are `(p = pMap->LookupTemporary(m_hWnd)) != NULL);` and `ASSERT((CWnd*)p == this);   // must be us`

Comment: 1. You did not load symbols for all DLLs on the call stack, so the call stack is not fully reliable. 2. When do you call SetTitle and from which thread? Please show the complete stack trace (you cut off the topmost ~10%).

Comment: what symbols are missing?

Comment: Thanks; updated the image to show the full call stack

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're accessing the view from outside of the main thread. In that case, MFC's internal map of `CWnd` to `HWND` won't find your window indeed. You should delegate the `SetTitle()` operation to the main thread.

Comment: haha great minds! I just this minute came across this article that brought me to that same conclusion (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/147578). I did NOT know it was doing that...

Comment: Can I ask - is there a more elegant way of doing that than `RegisterWindowMessage()` and `PostMessage`?

Comment: You could ask that as another question, but beware of terms like *more elegant* that can result in that question being closed as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Figured. Hence the "can I ask?" hehe. Thanks for your help!